# react-navigation-tabs - icons not aligned and covering text

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I cant seem to get the icons to align using the new react-navigation-tabs.....some icons are sitting higher than others.
Also the icons are covering the labels and Id like to have some margin between icon and label.
I tried the code `style={{textAlignVertical: 'center'}}` for the icons (from another question on SO) but that did not work either

Below is code

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import IconFA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IconMCI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';


const ProfileTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (
  <IconFA
    name="user-circle"
    size={35}
    color={tintColor}
  />
);
const SearchTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (
  <IconMCI
    name="account-search"
    size={45}
    color={tintColor}
    /*onPress={() => {
      console.log('HELP!!');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Search');
    }}*/
  />
);
const MessageTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (
  <IconFA
    name="envelope"
    size={35}
    color={tintColor}
  />
);



const SignedInTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: Profile,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Me',
        tabBarIcon: ProfileTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Search: {
      screen: Search,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: SearchTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Message: {
      screen: Message,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Message',
        tabBarIcon: MessageTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: '#42CBC8',
      inactiveTintColor: '#9A9F99',
      iconStyle: {
        width: 'auto',
        height: 20,
      },
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
      },

      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
        //borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderBottomColor: '#D3D3D3',
        paddingVertical: 2,
        height: 60,
      },
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
  }, 
);
```

....but this is what it looks like :(

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can u share ur code on [snack](https://snack.expo.io)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I styled the first icon and you can change it as necessary to fit your needs and then apply those to the other two icons as well.  If you need to understand what is going on better go ahead and apply `backgroundColor` attr to different elements.  Simply, I wrapped the icon component in a View and then gave that view some styling to fit the icon appropriately.

```
import {createMaterialTopTabNavigator} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import IconFA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
import IconMCI from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons';

import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LinksScreen from '../screens/LinksScreen';
import SettingsScreen from '../screens/SettingsScreen';

import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

const ProfileTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <IconFA
      style={styles.iconStyle}
      name="user-circle"
      size={35}
      color={tintColor}
    />
  </View>

);

const SearchTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (
  <IconMCI
    name="account-search"
    size={45}
    color={tintColor}
    /*onPress={() => {
      console.log('HELP!!');
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Search');
    }}*/
  />
);

const MessageTabBarIcon = ({tintColor}) => (
  <IconFA
    name="envelope"
    size={35}
    color={tintColor}
  />
);



export default SignedInTabNav = createMaterialTopTabNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Me',
        tabBarIcon: ProfileTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Search: {
      screen: LinksScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Search',
        tabBarIcon: SearchTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
    Message: {
      screen: SettingsScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarLabel: 'Message',
        tabBarIcon: MessageTabBarIcon,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    tabBarOptions: {
      showIcon: true,
      upperCaseLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: '#42CBC8',
      inactiveTintColor: '#9A9F99',
      labelStyle: {
        fontSize: 12,
        margin: 0
      },
      iconStyle: {
        flex: 1
      },
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
        height: 65,
        borderBottomColor: '#D3D3D3',
      },
    },
    animationEnabled: false,
  }, 
); 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    width: 50,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  }
});
```

[image: NavBar Example w/ left icon newly styled]

Comment: This worked for Android.....but for IOS the view is contraining the icon

Answer (score 1):

I added an empty tabBarLabel in the tab screen, and included the text inside the tabBarIcon.

```html
 <Tab.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={MainStackNavigator}
    options=
    {{
       tabBarLabel:"",
       tabBarIcon:() =>
       {
         return(
            <View>
              <Text>Home</Text>
            <Image 
            style={{ width:20,height:20 }}
source{require('./assets/home_white.png')}>
             </Image>
              </View>
               )
        }
    }} 
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

set `resizeMode` in your style section
such as :

```
<Image
    source={iconName}
    style={{ width: 25, height: 25, tintColor }}
    resizeMode={"contain"}
/>
```